# Angular: If-operations on $scope.variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I want to run a function based on a $scope value. In my controller, I have:

```
 $scope.value = "";
 $scope.selector = function(info) { 
    if ($scope.value === "") {
       $scope.value = info;
    } else {
       $scope.value = "";
    }
 }
```

The function is triggered on ng-click of different images, e.g.:

`<img ng-src="..." ng-click="selector(info)">`

My problem is the if-operations dont seem to work on the $scope value. I have also tried:

```
 $scope.$watch('value', function(val) {
    if(val === "") {
       $scope.value = info;
    }
 }
```

This works if it is outside a function, but not if I place it in the selector function. Better approaches always welcome. Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: Your function expects a parameter, you don't give it one.

Comment: This has been a typo, I m doing that already, I corrected that. The parameter is in the code. My problem is that he if function does not detect the $scope.value === ""

Comment: What is `info` in `ng-click="selector(info)"`?

Comment: A string that I get from a string array: e.g. imageName[0], which should be "Image 1"

Comment: It seems like if I run the function directly, the if function runs. But not if I assign the function to a $scope variable.

Comment: Version direct-run:
`tester();
  function tester() {
    if ($scope.value === "") {
      console.log("selected");
    } else {
      console.log("unselected");
    }
  }`

Results in "selected.

Comment: Inside $scope:
`$scope.selector = function () {
      if ($scope.value === "") {
        // $scope.value = info;
        console.log("selected");
      } else {
        // $scope.value = "";
        console.log("unselected");
      }
    }`

Results in unselected. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose your value inside an object. There are some cases where Angular cannot "see" that the variable changed.

So, try to keep something like:

```
$scope.value = { value: "" };
```

and change the rest of the code accordingly.

I did a codepen with some fixes in your code and with what I said to you:
[Running example](http://codepen.io/tuliofaria/pen/EZaJXm?editors=1111)

In this example you can see the val === "" returning true and false.

Comment: This did not solve it. The the if statement still results in false.

Comment: hi @sandboxj , I edited my answer with the if statement fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameter from the view to the function, because your function needs an input parameter

Change the view as,

```
img ng-src="..." ng-click="selector(value)">
```

Comment: Sorry, this has been a typo, I m doing that already, I corrected that. My problem is that he if function does not detect the $scope.value === "".

Comment: check if your function is getting called and the value being passed

Comment: I checked the value. I can console.log(info) and it shows up. But not if I place it inside the if function. Only if I place it before it.

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have any account for screensharing. I understand that if operations should normally be possible on $scope variables then?

Comment: @sandboxj yes it should work, probably you can debug and check if the function is getting called and print the value

Comment: Since when I place the console.log inside the function and it gets logged to the console, the function should run.  `$scope.value = "";
 $scope.selector = function(info) { 
console.log("here");    
if ($scope.value === "") {
       $scope.value = info;
    } else {
       $scope.value = "";
    }
 }`

Comment: The console.log also runs when I place it into the else-statement part: `$scope.value = ""; $scope.selector = function(info) { if ($scope.value === "") { $scope.value = info; } else { console.log("here"); $scope.value = ""; } }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132319/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sandboxj).

Comment: Should I mark this as the answer? Since it has been a different issue that you have solved.